# Hand computing betwenness centrality and edge betweenness in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$:

Betweenness centrality of a node $v$ is the sum of the fraction of all-pairs shortest paths that pass through $v$.

$c_B(e) =\sum_{s,t \in V} \frac{\sigma(s, t|e)}{\sigma(s, t)}$

where $V$ is the set of nodes, $\sigma(s,t)$ is the number of shortest
$(s,t)-$paths, and $\sigma(s, t|e)$  is the number of those paths passing through edge  $e$

Edge betweenness centrality is defined as the number of the shortest paths that go through an edge $e$ in a graph or network.

If I have a hand-made graphical representation of a single graph like the following:

[image]

And I want to compute the edge betwenness of (G,L) and the edge centrality of (I) and (E).

Is there a mechanical way by hand in which i can do it without getting too confused/considering actually all the possible shortest paths without missing any?

Note that for instance the betweenness centrality for I would require to weigh the $LIB$ path not as 1 but as 1/2 since there exist an alternative path not passing through $I$ that connectes $L$ to $B$, namely $LCB$.

How can I quickly find by hand all the shortest paths passing through such node?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to your question is: **Don't**.

How to do it "quickly"? Impossible. It is a very tedious computation even if you ignore the graph theory: wave a magic wand and get all the fractions instantly... you still have to add them up! Just how confident are you that you can correctly add a dozen fractions with common denominator 252? For myself, I'll just say that it's fortunate my life will never depend on such a task...

But if you are insistent, here are my thoughts. First of all, the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) on betweeness centrality has a discussion of algorithms. I didn't try any of them out myself, but Johnson's algorithm does not appear to be too unpleasant to do by hand. I'm assuming you knew this already and are looking for something that doesn't involve learning algorithms with fancy names.

The bad news is that in that case the answer is both very simple and probably not what you wanted to hear: you just have to pick a strategy for bookkeeping, and be very scrupulous about it. However, I want to highlight a strategy that is particularly efficient, and probably not one that you would stumble upon naturally unless you've seen some spectral graph theory.

> **Idea:** Recall that the number of minimum-length paths between $s$ and $t$ is the first $k$ such that $A^k$ has a nonzero $(s,t)$-entry, where $A$ is the graph's [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). By tracing through the proof, it's not hard to show that by replacing the $1$s corresponding to edge $e$ with a variable $x$, the first nonzero $(s,t)$-entry will be $a+bx$, where $b$ is the number of paths passing through $e$.

This perspective has several advantages.

- Probably most obvious is that the paths themselves have retreated into the arithmetic, so you can count them without the trouble of finding them.
- You can handle the vertices instead of edges by replacing all the $1$s in the vertex's column (or row, not both) with $x$. In so doing, the *total* number of paths is $a+b$, so you can even get the required fraction information.
- You can simply drop higher powers of $x$ when they appear. These correspond to walks that use $e$ or $v$ multiple times and hence never appear in any path.

This sounds wonderful in theory, but it cannot be overstated that you still have to compute powers of the adjacency matrix. If you've ever multiplied together sparce $12\times 12$ matrices by hand, you don't need me to tell you that keeping the indices straight is a monstrous effort (the arithmetic is not usually bad: the trouble is that there are so many zeros at first that it's easy to accidentally multiply the 5th row with the 8th column instead of the 7th). Graph paper normally helps, but less so with the $x$'s in the picture, because polynomial notation is "wider than it is tall" so you can't fit entries into a single square. (Although you might find multiplying new copies of $A$ on the *left* alleviates that somewhat.)

Finally, I want to end on a somewhat more ambivalent note: you may or may not find this a more acceptable use of the computer. Despite my fraction joke at the start, I know that eliminating technology isn't your goal. You're simply trying to reduce error while retaining the intuition from the calculation. To that end: you would, indeed, "feel" the paths as you performed the multiplication, and that will get lost if you just throw these matrices into a symbolic calculator. But if you're not super comfortable with (say) SAGE, I'm sympathetic that it's a lot easier to convince a computer to do matrix operations than graph algorithms.